# Unused b1/b2 valid visa

Tags: visas

I have a valid b1/b2 visa I obtained for the purpose of a conference last year, unfortunately I couldn't attend the conference for some family issues. Now I wish to use the visa this year, would that be allowed knowing that the conference has passed?

Answer (score 2):

U.S. visitor visas are not canceled or revoked simply because you were unable to use them for your originally intended visit. You can use the visa and enter the United States at any time up to its date of expiration, for any legitimate purpose allowed by the visa type. For instance, if you have a B-1/B-2 visa you can enter for tourism or business visits as long as the visa remains valid.

It is still a good idea to bring with you documents that show that you intend to leave the United States and that you can pay the costs of your visit, as well as proof of onward travel, as you are likely to be asked for these.

Comment: The second paragraph follows naturally, of course, from the principle that a US visa represents permission to apply at the border to be admitted; it does not itself constitute permission to enter.

Comment: The same is true of most if not all countries; the U.S. just makes it very explicit.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, I intend to spend a maximum of 7 days during this visit, pls what are the documents I need to provide at the POE to show I don't intend to overstay?thx

Comment: But there is a practical difference between Schengen visas, for example, and US visas: A US visitor's stay is not limited by the validity of the visa, while a Schengen visitor's stay is.  @kenny the documents depend on your situation.  For example, if you have evidence of stable employment in your country of residence, of home ownership, or of strong family ties, you should be prepared to present it.  I would also suggest that you refrain from volunteering it unless you are asked by the border officer.